# Audio/Video recording in messenger webview

Tags: webview, mediarecorder, messenger

I'm building a messenger bot in which I'm enabling an audio/video conversation through the messenger webview, like a channel or a chatroom. The audio recorder framework I implemented is working in webview and recording perfectly well, but not working in the messenger webview. In chrome or firefox as soon as we open this link, it asks the user to allow permission to this website to user Microphone. This is not working in messenger webview hence the recorder is not able to access the device microphone. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: did you find any solution?